# How to Add Filter Search Like Grid View In List View Yii2

Tags: php, web, yii, yii2, frameworks

I Want to Add Filter With List View (Some Thing Like What Is In Grid View) but I Don Not Know How Do That

Filters I Want Are CheckBox And DropDown Options.

Here Is My Action Code In SiteController

```
<?php

public function actionMobiles(){
   $searchModel = new MobileSearch();
    //$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);
 //$dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Mobile::find(),
    'pagination' => [
    'pageSize' => 1,
],
]);

// get the posts in the current page
//$posts = $dataProvider->getModels();
return $this->render('mobiles', ['dataProvider' => $dataProvider,'searchModel' => $searchModel]);


}

?>
```

In View File I Have 2 Files :

Here Is mobiles View :

```
 <?php
 use yii\widgets\ListView;
 use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\grid\GridView;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper ;
use app\models\Mobile;
 ?>

 <?= ListView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
       //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
      'itemView' => '_mobiles',

]); ?>
```

And In _mobiles I Have :

```
<?php
use yii\widgets\DetailView;
?>

<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        //'id',
        'id',
        'title',
        //'ativo',
    ],
]) ?>
```

It Shows Data From DataBase Correctly With It Pagination.
But How To Add Filter To Update List(CheckBox And DropDown List Are Use to Update)??

Comment: add 'filterModel' => $searchModel, in your widget

Comment: in list view??? @Gunnrryy

Comment: Setting unknown property: yii\widgets\ListView::filterModel
@Gunnrryy

Comment: yeah saw that, can you work with gridView or dataTables instead of listView?  any particular reason to pick listView?

Comment: @Gunnrryy  i want to list products and filtering them.i search many times and suggested  me to use list view

Comment: i think this type of display has to be listview

Comment: You can do the said functionality in grid view as well, and grid supports filtering as opposed to listView.. just try once and see if you get the desired results

Answer (score 0):

here is the code for you, you should replace attribute and model name according to yours.

```
    [
        'attribute' => 'attribute_name',
        'label' => 'Email',
        'value' => function($model){
            return $model->attribute_name;
        },
        'filterType' => GridView::FILTER_SELECT2,
        'filter' => \yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map([Your Model]::find()->asArray()->all(), 'id', 'email'),
        'filterWidgetOptions' => [
            'pluginOptions' => ['allowClear' => true],
        ],
        'filterInputOptions' => ['placeholder' => 'Email', 'id' => 'grid--search-email']
    ],
```

Comment: is that like other gridviews?
can be pagination?

Comment: it is just an another attribute inside grid view.  you can add it as a new column, can be paginated too.

Answer (score -1):

Add this line in your view file,
Just above listview widget

echo $this->render('_search', ['model' => $searchModel]);